# Create the same Response in Spring Boot as in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, spring-boot, rest

Look at the following REST-API created in Node.js

NodeJS:

```
app.get("/stockData/:name", (req, res) => {
  // Get All Data
  db.query(
    "SELECT date, close FROM stocks WHERE name ='" +
      req.params.name +
      "'ORDER BY date AND name",
    (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.json(results);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

If I do a request i get the following response structure:

[image]

Now i need to build the same in REST-API and SQL-Query in Spring Boot. So that I get the same response. I tried it with this code:

Spring Boot:

```
//Controller
@RestController
public class ApiController {
    @Autowired
    private StockRepository stockRepository;
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @GetMapping("/stockData/{name}")
    public double[] getStockData(@PathVariable String name) {
        return stockRepository.getStockData(name);
        
    }

//Repo
@Query(value = "SELECT a.date, a.close FROM stocks AS a WHERE a.name = ?1 ORDER BY a.date AND a.name", nativeQuery = true)
    double[] getStockData(String name);
```

But it doesnt work...
Does somebody know how i can implement the same in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json shows an array of objects with attributes date and close but you are returning a double[] from getSockData(). You need to create a class that contains attributes date and close and return a list of these objects instead. Use json formatting annotations for the date if needed.